# Can I somehow get jQuery size smaller if I only target to WebKit?

Tags: jquery, iphone, cross-browser, filesize

When been looking ZeptoJs and started to assume if I would be able to remove all IE&Firefox specific stuff I would get very small jQuery file.

Is there a tool or some code generator that removes all browser/version specific code so I can target to specific browser and get jquery file size smaller?

I am writing application to iPhone and I would like to use jQuery but only with webkit-engine. Something like Zeptojs does but I want to stay on jQuery.

Comment: What about [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)?

Comment: Of course you can. It will take you a fair bunch of time digging the code and testing.

Good luck :)

Comment: I would like to get normal jQuery file smaller. Jquery Mobile is just an extension to jQuery.

Comment: You'd probably be better off just using a commonly used CDN-hosted file like Google.